# Semantics of ALSA PCM calls

Tags: c, linux, audio, capture, alsa

Hi I am writing a program that has to capture from three input devices at the same time (in this case, it's three identical USB webcams).

First of all, ALSA is not based on the familiar UNIX paradigm "everything is a file" so I cannot use the regular poll(3) call; knowing that the data stream should be steady among all devices, for now I do something like:

```
while(!stop)
  for(i = 0; i < input_device_count; i++)
  {
    snd_pcm_readi(handle[i], buffer, frames);
    write(fd_out[i], buffer, size);
  }
```

This code iterates over each device and reads from it, writing the result on a file previously open. It works but I suspect there is a better way to do this, also using mmap so I do not have to copy from Kernel-space to user and to Kernel again.

For a moment, let's assume the three inputs stay in sync; the above code still does not guarantee that I will begin to record from the three devices *at the same time*. Is there a way to guarantee that? In fact, what are the semantics of calls like snd_pcm_prepare() and snd_pcm_start()? Right now I am not using those, I just go straight to snd_pcm_readi().

I have tried to search for code examples but I haven't found anything that has to do with multiple captures at the same time. Any hint would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALSA is based on the familiar UNIX paradigm "everything is a file"; so to handle multiple devices, you should use poll(3).

There are ALSA plugins that are implemented on top of multiple files, so there might be more than one handle per PCM device.
Call [snd_pcm_poll_descriptors_count](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#gac7f4cdb1c930b8d343714f60afa02fc4) for each device to know how many `pollfd` structures you need, then call [snd_pcm_poll_descriptors](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga742e8705f6992fd0e36efc868e574f01) to get the file handles and the respective `event` bits.

In your loop, after calling `poll`, you must not read the vales in the `pollfd` structures directly but call [snd_pcm_poll_descriptors_revents](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga7e561f305702c6f52dab49b6c84f7df7) to translate them back.

---

To ensure that multiple devices start at the same time, call [snd_pcm_link](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#gac6c33091b049985baa6466e8fe93917e).
However, this does not guarantee that the devices will run at the same speed.

Comment: I do not underdstand why you say ALSA uses the file concept. snd_pcm_readi() uses an opaque handler that does not give me any file descriptor. I am using exclusively "hw:" devices; it is an embedded system so I want to avoid any software conversion.

Comment: I am having a look at these functions you have mentioned, I really hope to find an example because this is a pattern that I haven't used before. Why snd_pcm_open() does not return a regular file handle is beyond me.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on snd_pcm_link(). Yes I know about the difference in clocks, I will have to experiment there. In any case, could you clarify the semantics of snd_pcm_prepare() and snd_pcm_start()?

Comment: By default, the stream is started when you have written some data. `snd_pcm_prepare()` is needed after an underrun. For a poll example, see `alsa-lib/test/pcm.c`.

Comment: Well this is about capture, so the stream is started when I read something? Why such calls like snd_pcm_start() and snd_pcm_prepare() exist?

Comment: You might want to start the the device later, so it's possible to change the start threshold.